# rust std::time::SystemTime::elapsed() error conversion to string

Tags: rust

given a std::time::SystemTime in the past, I'd like to manipulate elapsed() in a method via:

```
fn render(&self) -> Result<(), String> {
...
let elapsed = self.start.elapsed()?.as_secs();
...
}
```

however, ? operator wants to convert std::time::SystemTimeError to String, and From for std::time::SystemTimeError doesn't provide such a conversion. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can:

```
impl From<std::time::SystemTimeError> for std::time::SystemTimeError {
fn from(e: std::time::SystemTimeError) -> Self { ... }
}
```

I really don't want to have to add match to handle this, nor do I simply want to unwrap() without error checking. I could define a fn that wraps the match and returns a Result<std::time::Duration, String>, but that seems misguided. What am I missing?

Update:
After much futzing around with snafu; yes, I really like it. Adding the SystemTimeError was a breeze. However, it took me a while to sort out how to deal with the errors returned from the other crated (where they are Result<(), String>. I finally found that I just needed to add a GenericError to my Error enum and then implement std::convert::From for Error to create the GenericError.

Comment: You probably better make the result type more generic rather than trying to convert error into `String`.

Comment: Error type generally implement display and everything that implement display implement ToString.

Comment: I used Result<(), String> due to a using a crate that implements many methods that return Result<(), String>  (calls to crate not shown). Should I introduce a new trait here or generic that handles String and std::time::SystemTimeError, and what do I do about the next case I run into? It seems like From<T> was designed to handle this and I'm just missing something -- I'm a rust noob.

Comment: if you want clean error handle I advice you https://crates.io/crates/snafu

Comment: snafu does seem to offer a solution. I'm concerned about the weightiness of it -- but its likely that's me, just not mind-melding with rust yet.

Answer (score 0):

Most people (myself included) will advise against using `String` with `Result`, as you can lose Error information that way. However I don't think that's the whole story. For your example, you can use the venerable [map_err](//doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err):

```
let elapsed = self.start.elapsed().map_err(|e|
   e.to_string()
)?;
```

as detailed by [Andrew Gallant](//blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling). If you want to include full Error object,
you can do something like this:

```
let elapsed = self.start.elapsed().map_err(|e|
   format!("{:?}", e)
)?;
```

Or, depending on the situation you might be able to [avoid both](//doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_default) Results and
panics:

```
let elapsed = self.start.elapsed().unwrap_or_default();
```